# Meteor - Autoform break a list of checkboxs into equal columns

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm currently using autoform with bootstrap styling to create a form. The form contains a list of fruit. Users need to check the fruit they like which is then saved to the database. Since there is a lot of fruit I would like to have the list generate equal col-sm-4 to make use of larger screens and prevent a single  column list.

```
{{> afQuickField name='profile.pastEmployer' class="select-checkbox" input-col-class="col-sm-4"}}
```